# Doctrine Record Listener

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, listener, record

I have a listener which contains a preSave() method. Is there a way for me to halt doctrine
from calling the save method if a condition fails. Unfortunately I am not allowed to throw an exception. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first idea would be to set a flag in the preSave()-method and to check for that flag in the save()-method. But I think skipOperation() is what you are looking for:

```
public function preSave(Doctrine_Event $event)
{
    if (!$condition) {
        $event->skipOperation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that is awesome! I never knew about skipOperation! Awesome!

Comment: i will try the skipOperation.......but I am not sure about the flag approach since the preSave() is called after the save() method of our model but before the Doctrine_Record'd save() method